# Run function on a timer

Tags: java

I tried to set a function that adds interest to a balance on a timer. I have tried using the timerstack function and scheduled executor service.

This is the function. It works on its own manually. I would like to make it run every 3 minutes.

```
public void interest_rate() 
    {   double interest = 2 ;
        balance = balance * (1 + (interest/100));
}
```

Comment: It might be more efficient if you do all these at the same moment every time you fetch the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.util.Timer` & `java.util.TimerTask` Api for scheduling tasks
at repeated intervals along with initial delay time. Please check out the
[example](http://www.journaldev.com/1050/java-timer-and-timertask-example-tutorial) for better understanding.

you can check out this `Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate` method [api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long))